# Can someone show me how to write and override methods in order to find the geometric mean of up to 6 inputs of percentages

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I am unfamiliar with defining methods and overriding them, please explain to me if you can.

This is what I have so far.
I need to allow the user to input 1-6 years as well as a percentage increase or decrease for each year then I need to find the geometric mean of those numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GeometricMean_slm
{
//not sure if this is neccessary or proper
   public double average;
   public double y1;
   public double y2;
   public double y3;
   public double y4;
   public double y5;
   public double y6;
   public static void geometricMean6()
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the length of time of the investment (1 to 6 years):");
      int years = keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Please enter the percent increase or decrease for each year:");
      double y1 = keyboard.nextInt();
      double y2 = keyboard.nextInt();
      double y3 = keyboard.nextInt();
      double y4 = keyboard.nextInt();
      double y5 = keyboard.nextInt();
      double y6 = keyboard.nextInt();
   }
//neither method will execute when I run
   public void main(String[] args)
   {  
         geometricMean6();
         average = (double)Math.pow(y1 * y2 * y3 * y4 * y5 * y6, .16);
         System.out.println("end"+ average);                
   }      
}
```

This code needs to be repeated 1-6 times depending on how many years the user inputs. I also need the program to prompt the user for another input after running, which I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the reason, your method is not being executed is that your main method is not static, it should look something like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

     geometricMean6();
     average = (double)Math.pow(y1 * y2 * y3 * y4 * y5 * y6, .16);
     System.out.println("end"+ average);                
}
```

Then the second problem is that you don't need those that are assigned out of the function "geometricMean" , even if you do you should make them static in order to access them in your main function. Since you have to get the geometric mean I have changed your function from void to double, in order to return some result. Which is as follows:

```
public static double geometricMean6()
{
    double result = 1;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the length of time of the investment (1 to 6 years):");
    int years = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the percent increase or decrease for each year:");
    double input = keyboard.nextDouble();
    result *= input;
    int i = 1;
    while(i < years){
        input = keyboard.nextDouble();
        i++;
        result *= input;
    }
    result = (double) Math.pow(result, (double) 1 / years);
    return result;
}
```

Here I have assigned a double result in order to return the final result. While loop is achieving the goal of having multiple inputs. It will go as far as the "years" input. Then, I have multiplied all of the inputs that the user enters. Finally, the code calculates the geometric mean in the function and returns the result. That is why in the main function all you have to do is call the function and print out the result that it returns. Which is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.println("Average is : " + geometricMean6());

}
```

Hope it helped. Have a nice day!

Comment: Is there a way to make it accept negative numbers as inputs?

Comment: It should be accepting negative numbers already. But from what i understand, i think you should enter a number in range of 0-1 in order to have a "decrease".